# Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться

Tags: java

Напишите класс Printer, со статическими функциями print() для вывода чисел и массивов примитивных типов double и int.

См. примеры.

Пример:

Test    Выходные данные

```
Printer.print(5)
5
Printer.print(0.5)
0.5
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
Printer.print(a);
[1,2,3]
double[] a = {1., 2.71, 3.1415};
Printer.print(a);
[1.0,2.71,3.1415]
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? В перегрузке метода print?

Comment: Верно, не могу понять, как осуществить

Answer (score 2):

```
class Printer {

    public static void print(int value) {
        ....
    }

    public static void print(double value) {
        .....
    }

    public static void print(int[] value) {
        ......
    }

}
```